# Tracking form submissions with Goals/Type=Destination in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I created a goal with a **required** funnel. My URL's aren't clean, thus I am using `REGEX` to match.

- Funnel step: `Site.com/results/?session=43903549035490345` Regex: `\/results\/\?session=`
- Goal step:   `Site.com/results/bestquotes/?00000@xyz` Regex: `\/results\/bestquotes\/\?`

Problem 1: In the real-time conversions view, the funnel isn't being respected, meaning if I refresh the page the counter is registering another hit.

Problem 2: In Conversions>Goals>Overviews - No information is present on this screen.

screenshot: (just because I need someone to confirm I'm not insane) :)
[image: Google Analytics Account Snapshot]

Comment: Bueller? Bueller? Anyone? Bueller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Regexs look like they should be working. Still, I think you can try to do this with a **Begins with** rule instead of a regular expression. It would be much more readable.

1. Begins with `/results/?session=`
2. Begins with `/results/bestquotes/?`

Have you tried this?

Comment: Logged in today. Hit verify. Seems to be working now. Very strange. I did try your suggestion prior. Thanks for answering anyway.